# Crear ejecutable codigo tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller, scipy

Estoy intentando crear un ejecutable de un código con librerías como *Tkinter*, *Pandas* y *Pillow*.

He utilizado el `pyinstllaer`, `cx_freeze` y `scipy` pero obtengo un error o el `.exe` tiene un tamaño no acorde a lo que se quiere (ej: 500 mb).

Lo que quiero obtener es un ejecutable para poder abrirlo en Windows y/o MAC para ser utilizado por la mayoría de los usuarios.

El código puede ser algo irrelevante para esta pregunta, por lo que necesito o quizás necesitamos todos son consejos o tutoriales entendibles para poder crear un ejecutable, ya que en la preguntas revisadas solo se está resolviendo casos específicos y no casos comunes como lo que estoy describiendo. Gracias.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
#from sismorresistente import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import Image
import pandas as pd
import os

class sismicidad():
    def __init__(self):
        self.vent_sismi = tk.Tk()
        self.vent_sismi.iconbitmap("sismo_ico_1.ico")
        self.vent_sismi.title("SISMICIDAD")
        self.pest_sismor = ttk.Notebook(self.vent_sismi)
        self.pest_sismor.grid(row=0, column = 0)
        self.sismorresistente_1()
        self.perf_suelos()
        self.zona_sismi()
        self.sismor_funcion()
        self.z_sismi_funcion()
        self.vent_sismi.mainloop()

#Funciones para la estructura de la pestaña SONAS SISMORRESISTENTE:
    def sismorresistente_1(self):
        ...
#Funcion de CERRAR:
    def cerrar_sismicidad(self):
        self.vent_sismi.destroy()

#Funciones para la estructura de la pestaña de PERFILES DE SUELOS:
    def perf_suelos(self):
        ...
    #Mostrar Tabla de Vs:
    def abrir_vs(self):
        self.im = Image.open("C:/Users/Miguel Mogollòn/Desktop/sismicidad/tabla_perf.jpg")
        self.im.show()

    #Funciones para PERFILES DE SUELOS:
    def sismor_funcion(self,event=None):

        self.x1=self.entry_1.get()

        try:
            self.x1=int(self.x1)

        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Escribir solo números enteros.")

        while True:
            if self.x1 > 1500:
                self.eti_lab_11.configure(text="Perfil tipo S0: Roca Dura.", font = "helvetica 12", foreground= "blue")
                self.eti_lab_11.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

            elif self.x1 > 500 and self.x1 <= 1500:
                self.eti_lab_11.configure(text="Perfil tipo S1: Roca y Suelos muy rigidos.", font = "helvetica 12", foreground= "blue")
                self.eti_lab_11.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

            elif self.x1 > 180 and self.x1 <= 500:
                self.eti_lab_11.configure(text="Perfil tipo S2: Suelos Intermedios.", font = "helvetica 12", foreground= "blue")
                self.eti_lab_11.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

            elif self.x1 > 0 and self.x1 <= 180:
                self.eti_lab_11.configure(text="Perfil tipo S3: Suelos Blandos.", font = "helvetica 12", foreground= "blue")
                self.eti_lab_11.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

            elif self.x1 == 0:
                self.eti_lab_11.configure(text="")
                self.eti_lab_11.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

            break

#Funciones para la estrutura de la pestaña ZONAS SISMICAS:
    def zona_sismi(self, event=None):
        ...
    def abrir_norma(self):
        os.popen("C:/Users/Miguel Mogollòn/Desktop/sismicidad/norma_tecnica_e_030.pdf")

    def z_sismi_funcion(self, event=None):

        self.datos = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Miguel Mogollòn/Desktop/sismicidad/distri_sism_1.csv", encoding="latin9", sep=";")
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(self.datos)

        self.x2 = self.entry_2.get()

        try:
            self.x2=str(self.x2)

        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Escribir el distrito.")

        #while True:

        self.x2 = str.upper(self.x2)

        for self.idx in self.df.index:

            if self.df.DISTRITO[self.idx] == self.x2:
                self.eti_lab_14.configure(text = f"La zona sismica de '{self.x2}' es: {self.df.ZONA_SISMICA[self.idx]}", font="helvetica 12", foreground = "blue")
                #self.eti_lab_14.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
                self.eti_lab_14.place(x=30, y=70)
                break
        else:
            self.eti_lab_14.configure(text=f"Ingrese el distrito correcto",font="helvetica 12", foreground="blue")
            self.eti_lab_14.place(x=30, y=70)
            #self.eti_lab_14.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

aplicacion = sismicidad()
```

Adjunto imagen de error:
[image: Error]

Comment: Usas anaconda? creo que pandas usa bastante espacio, pero no debería ser tanto. He visto problemas con builds usando Anaconda, en la que el freezer crea el ejecutable pero incluye todas las librerías instaladas en tu environment (no solo las que usa el programa)

Comment: Uso la plataforma de _Pycharm_, y tengo un entorno virtual específico para el proyecto donde estan instaladas las librerías que utilizo. Anteriormente tambien utilizaba _Pycharm_ pero con la diferencias que tenia varias librerías instaladas en ese entorno virtual; luego hice otro entorno virutal y creé el proyecto; lo que pasa ahora es que el ejecutable no lo abre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usé la plataforma de `pyinstaller` para compilarlo en el ejecutable con el código en la ventana CMD:

```
pip install auto-py-to-exe


auto-py-to-exe
```